# MongoDB does´t start, exit code 203

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, virtual-machine

I installed MongoDB on the Ruspberry pi desktop on a VM, then I started it with the following command:

> sudo service mongod start

The result of this command is the following:

```
systemctl list-unit-files --state enabled
```

`mongodb.service enabled`

Then when I check the status using

> sudo service mongod status

The other issue is that there´s no .sock file in my /tmp folder.

PS: I removed MongoDB and reinstalled it trying to fix the issue but I always get the same problem.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance.

I get the following error:

````
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-06-08 12:33:17 CEST; 3s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 22168 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 22168 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jun 08 12:33:17 raspberry systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Jun 08 12:33:17 raspberry systemd[22168]: mongod.service: Failed to execute command: Exec format error
Jun 08 12:33:17 raspberry systemd[22168]: mongod.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/mongod: Exec format error
Jun 08 12:33:17 raspberry systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jun 08 12:33:17 raspberry systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.```
````

Comment: Did you try this solution? https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=232295

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No I didn´t try this solution, I don´t see how it is related to my problem! can you explain please?

Comment: Just open the link and go through comments. And if you will search for error in the google, you will see its related to `systemd`

Comment: @tbhaxor Thank you so much for your help, I tried those commands, and it seems that mongodb service is enabled, but i still get the error ! do you have any other explanation?